# How much money can you get at Canadian Research universities versus US Research Universities in engineering/CS/Computational biology?

Tags: phd, computer-science, biology, electrical-engineering

What is the common range of research money can you get at Canadian Research universities versus US Research Universities in engineering/CS/Computational biology? I am asking on some idea from personal grants, supervisor grants, research assistantships etc.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Based on the tag, are you talking about   receiving research funding as a PhD student?  The situation would be quite different for faculty.

Comment: For the US, each school sets its own pay scale for graduate research assistants.

Comment: Please upvote my question back. Even grad phd students can get grants when they are mature enough in their research ? So why is my second question shot down ?

Comment: Let me be more clear with my suggestions. (1) Please ask only one question per post.  Thus you should edit the second question out of this post.  You could make a new question post to ask it, but please read http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/35284/does-the-nsf-award-grants-to-foreign-researchers-not-affiliated-with-us-instutit first, since it might answer your question or be a duplicate.

Comment: (2) Please clarify your question 1.  Are you talking about funding for a PhD student, or a faculty member?  Are you talking about funding through a student's own (internal or external) grant, through a research assistantship funded by a university or a supervisor's grant, or something else?  Are you talking about a theoretical maximum, or a common range?

Comment: changed the question after comments.

Comment: I'm afraid this still isn't clear on what funding you are asking about. Money for equipment, personal stipend, tuition, health insurance, travel (with or without having a publication) - all are different, come from different sources, and very heavily according to field, place, and what you are asking for.

Comment: I did change the text but not the heading of the question. Still not clear ?

Comment: You say "research money", but you mention assistantship which usually only provides personal stipend to you for living expenses and such, so I'm still not clear what you are asking. Do you want to know personal monthly income for living, funds available for you specifically to spend on research in the form of equipment/software/participants, or travel funding - or all of the above? Are you concerned about having money to live, or budget to spend on the research itself? Right now it's a range of $0 - $100,000+ per year, but I doubt that's very helpful.